# Java and simulating a Process Schedular

Tags: java

I really appreciate all the help given but i'm now struggling with the final part of the task, which is to make the increments and decrements happen in alternation. Ive edited to include the whole of my main class and the class incrementer which contains a for loop that calls **Main.increment** a given number of times (there is a class decrementer which is styled the same way as icrementer so i didn't include it). Could you help with how I might achieve this. If ive understood correctly i'm looking to make the value of **sharedValue** toggle between 1 and 0.

```
public class Main extends Thread {

private static int sharedValue = 0;
private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

public static void increment() {
    semaphore.down();
    sharedValue++;
    semaphore.up();
}

public static void decrement() {
    semaphore.down();
    sharedValue--;
    semaphore.up();
}

static int numberOfCycles = 20000;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    incrementer inc = new incrementer(numberOfCycles);
    inc.start();
    inc.join();

    decrementer dec = new decrementer(numberOfCycles);
    dec.start();
    dec.join();

    System.out.println(sharedValue);

}}
```

Semaphore class

```
private int count;
// Constructor
public Semaphore(int n) {
    count = n;
}

// Only the standard up and down operators are allowed.
public synchronized void down() {

    while (count == 0) {

        try {
            wait(); // Blocking call.
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        }
    }
    count--;
}

public synchronized void up() {
    count++;
    notify();
  }
}
```

Incrementer Class

public class incrementer extends Thread{

private int numberOfIncrements;

```
public incrementer(int numOfIncrements){
     numberOfIncrements = numOfIncrements;
} 
public void run(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfIncrements; i++){
    Main.increment();
}
}
```

}

Thanks again.

Comment: in OS book you can see Process Schedular. in all of OS book speaking about semaphore

Answer (score 3):

I think he means protected by the semaphore. So, you would use something like:

```
class ProtectedCount {
    private static int sharedValue = 0;
    private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    public void increment() {
        semaphore.down(); // wait till the semaphore is available
        sharedValue++;
        semaphore.up(); // tell everyone that the semaphore is available
    }
    // same thing for decrement()
}
```

This demonstrates using a semaphore to provide mutual exclusion. This use case is similar to a mutex. See [semaphore vs. mutex on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semaphores_vs._mutexes).

Comment: Thats really helpful thank you but ive got a few questions about your answer. What has happened to sharedValue and how does your solution make it protected? I also realised i forgot to ask in the original post but what is meant by wrap the calls around the operators.

Answer (score 0):

In the Semaphore class you may want ensure the "up" method doesn't increment the count beyond "n" that is passed in the constructor.

```
// Constructor
public Semaphore(int n) {
    count = n;
}

public synchronized void up() {
    count++; //Ensure count doesn't exceed n.
    notify();
  }
```